# Windows 8 - How To Change Live Tile Background Image?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, live-tile, windows-store-apps

How do I change the background image of a live tile in my Windows 8 app to a local image? The XML for the template I am using is:

```
<tile>
  <visual>
    <binding template="TileWideImageAndText01">
      <image id="1" src="image1.png" alt="alt text"/>
      <text id="1">Text Field 1</text>
    </binding>  
  </visual>
</tile>
```

For the text, I use

```
        XmlDocument xmltile= Windows.UI.Notifications.TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(Windows.UI.Notifications.TileTemplateType.TileWideImageAndText01);

        xmltile.GetElementsByTagName("text")[0].AppendChild(xmltile.CreateTextNode("73°F, Mostly Cloudy"));

        TileNotification tileupdate = new Windows.UI.Notifications.TileNotification(xmltile);

        Windows.UI.Notifications.TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tileupdate);
```

But what about for the image?

Comment: Certainly didn't expect this to get so many views

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868253%28v=win.10%29.aspx#supply_an_image_for_your_notification):

> The following code uses a local image from the app's package. This
>   type of image is included in your Visual Studio solution file and is
>   packaged as part of your app. These images are accessed by using the
>   "ms-appx:///" prefix. As a best practice, we also assign optional alt
>   text for accessibility purposes such as screen readers.

```
XmlNodeList tileImageAttributes = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
((XmlElement)tileImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///images/redWide.png");
((XmlElement)tileImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("alt", "red graphic");
```